# Angular2: How to transform my tree model to fit a different interface?

Tags: angular, primeng

Suppose that I have an employee class that looks something like this:

```
export class Employee {

    jobTitle: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    boss: Employee;
    workers: Employee[];

    constructor(jobTitle: string, firstName: string, lastName: string){
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public addWorker(worker: Employee){
        this.wokers.push(worker);
        worker.boss = this;
    }

}
```

Suppose that we have initial `Employee`s that look something like this:

```
function getInitialStaff(): Employee {

    let headWaiter: Employee = new Employee( "Head Waiter", "Sarah", "Hilton" );
    headWaiter.addWorker(new Employee("Bus Boy", "Joe", "BeefEater"));
    headWaiter.addWorker(new Employee("Waiter", "Randy", "Rainman"));

    let headCheif: Employee = new Employee( "Head Cheif", "Phil", "Yorstomux" );
    headWaiter.addWorker(new Employee("Dishwasher", "Andy", "Shark"));

    let owner: Employee = new Employee( "Owner", "Boris", "Laughington" );
    owner.addWorker(headWaiter);
    owner.addWorker(headCheif);
    return owner;
}
```

We can also assume that sometimes employees will be hired or fired.  Something along the lines of this:

```
window.setTimeout(()=>{
    let someEmployee: Employee = /* Some existing employee */
    someEmployee.addWorker("someTitle", "someName", "someLastName");
}, someAmountOfTime);
```

---

I want to display employees in a [PrimeNg tree](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree).

The tree widget requires that the data to be displayed conforms to the treeNode interface, which looks like this:

```
export interface TreeNode {
    label?: string;
    data?: any;
    icon?: any;
    expandedIcon?: any;
    collapsedIcon?: any;
    children?: TreeNode[];
    leaf?: boolean;
}
```

**Main Question:** Without changing my Employee class, what is the best way to transform the data into TreeNodes?

---

Things that I am thinking about:

- When I add a new Employee, I want to maintain my tree state (what is open, what is selected, etc)
- I need to be able to easily retrieve the employee that is currently selected.
- I am trying to avoid maintaining two duplicate models.
- I want to take advantage of Angular2's change detection in a reasonable, but scalable way

---

This is what my EmployeeTree component look like at the moment:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'employee-tree',
    template: `
        <div>
            <p-tree>
                /* Open Question, I need to transform owner and then tie the resulting TreeNode to the tree */
            </p-tree>
        </div>
    `
    directives: [ Tree ]
})
export class EmployeeTree {
    @Input()
    private owner: Employee;
}
```

---

**Option 1** - Create a pipe that will transform an Employee into TreeNode

I guess that would leave my template looking like this:

```
<p-tree [value]="owner | convertToTreeNode"></p-tree>
```

And I would create a pipe that did something like this:

```
@Pipe({name: 'convertToTreeNode'})
export class ToTreeNode implements PipeTransform {
    transform(employee: Employee): TreeNode {

        let treeNode: TreeNode = {
            label: employee.firstName + " " + employee.lastName,
            data: employee,
            children: []
        };

        employee.workers.forEach(worker => {
            treeNode.children.push(this.transform(worker));
        })

        return treeNode;

    }
}
```

Pros/Cons:

- This takes advantage of angular's change detection
- If this is a pure pipe, it may miss changes
- If this is an impure pipe, it may be too heavy
- Leaves the component very clean and delegates responsibility to the pipe
- Not sure if this will preserve my gui state (what is selected and what is open/closed) when a new item is added

---

**Option 2** - Inside the component maintain a separate structure for the tree

```
@Component({
    selector: 'employee-tree',
    template: `
        <div>
            <p-tree [data]="employeeTree">
            </p-tree>
        </div>
    `
    directives: [ Tree ]
})
export class EmployeeTree {
    @Input()
    private owner: Employee;

    private employeeTree: TreeNode;

    // TODO - Somehow watch the owner for changes (how?) and then repopulate the employeeTree
}
```

I think that I could make the Employee emit an event that trickles up when it changes.  This could give me something to hook into.

---

Generally speaking, what is the best way to use Angular2 to do something like this.

To summarize, I want to use a widget that expects data in a *slightly* different format than what I am storing it in.  What is the standard angular2 way to massage my data into the widget?  Is there special angular2 sauce that will help me here?  Should I maintain two separate models?  Potentially my tree could have 100s or possibly 1000s of items in it, so I am somewhat concerned with performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Lodash [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map). Here's their canned example:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney' },
  { 'user': 'fred' }
];

// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.map(users, 'user');
// => ['barney', 'fred']
```

Here's my twist on that:

```js
let emplData = [
         {  "jobTitle": "Paperboy",
            "firstName": "Fred",
            "lastName":  "Bloggs"
         },
         {  "jobTitle": "Tea boy",
            "firstName": "Charlie",
            "lastName":  "Creamslice"
         }         
    ]
   let resEl = document.getElementById("result");
   resEl.innerText =JSON.stringify(emplData.map(buildEmployeeNamesOnlyAndAddSeqNo));

    function buildEmployeeNamesOnlyAndAddSeqNo({firstName,lastName},index) {
       return {seqNo:index, firstName, lastName}
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.2/lodash.js"></script>

  <div id="result">
      
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have subclass of Employee where it conforms to TreeNode

Then in your component

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'employee-tree',
        template: `
            <div>
                <p-tree [data]="employeeNode.label">
                </p-tree>
            </div>
        `
        directives: [ Tree ]
    })
    export class EmployeeNode extends Employee implements TreeNode {

        // -- No need for this anymore -- @Input() private owner: EmployeeNode;
        @Input() private jobTitleInput: String;
        @Input() private firstNameInput: String;
        @Input() private lastNameInput: String;

        constructor(){
            super(jobTitleInput, firstNameInput, lastNameInput);

            // Populate TreeNode here for example label from TreeNode
            this.label = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
      }

        //private employeeTree: TreeNode; -- No need for TreeNode object any more as EmployeeNode contains both TreeNode and Employee

        // TODO - Somehow watch the owner for changes (how?) and then repopulate the employeeTree : Just add a setter for each property 
of Employee that you want to also affect TreeNode field and inside that setter update in your EmployeeNode class the field of TreeNode Interface like 'this.label = 'updated value'
    }
```